# How to consume an api that returns callback with isomorphic-fetch?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to consume this open api

http://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts?filter[orderby]=rand&filter[posts_per_page]=1&_jsonp=mycallback

which returns a callback. like this

```
mycallback([{
  "ID": 1867,
  "title": "Robert Brownjohn (when asked What is graphic design?)",
  "content": "<p>I am.<\/p>\n",
  "link": "https:\/\/quotesondesign.com\/robert-brownjohn\/",
  "custom_meta": {
    "Source": "<ahref=\"http:\/\/www.nytimes.com\/2011\/12\/12\/arts\/design\/the-man-who-broke-the-record-on-let-it-bleed.html\">article<\/a>"
  }
}])
```

I have tried this

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import 'isomorphic-fetch';

const url = 'http://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts?filter[orderby]=rand&filter[posts_per_page]=1&_jsonp=mycallback';

const headers = new Headers({'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*'});

const options = {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: headers,
    mode: 'no-cors'
};

const getQuote = () => {
    fetch(url, options)
    .then(res => {
        console.log(res)
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
    })
}

class App extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        getQuote();
    }

    render() {
        return (
          <div className="App">
              Hello World
          </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

how to use isomorphic-fetch to consume this api?

Comment: Is this code intended to run on a server, or in a browser?

Comment: I want to use this in browser.

Comment: I can't find any documentation on isomorphic-fetch providing support for jsonp. jQuery provides support for jsonp. Have you considered using that?

Comment: yeah that works, is there any alternative package except for jquery? or other way to bypass cors issue from front end?

Comment: [This library](https://github.com/camsong/fetch-jsonp) apparently allows using a fetch-like interface to query jsonp. And no, I'm pretty sure jsonp is the only way to get around cross-domain query restrictions without CORS.

Comment: thanks for your help. :)